# blazor IJSRuntime How to function (clickEvent) { ... }

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly, froala

I'm building an application with Froala HTML Editor. The basic functionality I get to work, however I did not succeed in the Events part.

The following code is for JavaScript ([Froala doc](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events/#contentChanged))

```
new FroalaEditor('.selector', {
  events: {
   'contentChanged': function () {
     // Do something here.
     // this is the editor instance.
     console.log(this);
   }
  }
});
```

The code I got working looks like this

```
var config = new FroalaEditorConfig()
    {
         ToolbarInline = true,
         CharCounterCount = false,
         Key = KEY,
    };
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("FroalaEditor", ".selector", config);
```

I tried to add the following arguemtn after Key

```
Events = new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
       {"contentChanged", "function () { DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('PubbleCloud.Frontend.Client', 'PubbleCloud.Frontend.Client.Shared.Form.ContentChanged'); }"},
       {"click", "function () { DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('PubbleCloud.Frontend.Client', 'PubbleCloud.Frontend.Client.Shared.Form.Click'); }"}
   }
```

This returns the error: `Uncaught TypeError: l.opts.events[e].apply is not a function`

where I created the following function and tried both with static and object functions.

```
[JSInvokable]
public static void ContentChanged()
{
    Console.WriteLine("ContentChanged");
}
```

Is there any way I can add a call to my blazor functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, I'm not happy about it yet, but it works.

I would love to know if there is a way to do this without a separate js file.

First you need to create a js file.

```
dotNetHelper = null;

function setDotNetHelper(value) {
    dotNetHelper = value;
}

function createEditor(el) {
    return new FroalaEditor(el,
        {
            toolbarInline: true,
            charCounterCount: false,
            events: {
                'contentChanged': function () {
                    dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('ContentChanged');
                },
                'click': function () {
                    dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('Click');
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The blazor object looks like this`FroalaEditor.razor.cs`

```
public sealed partial class FroalaEditor : IDisposable
{
    [Inject] private IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    private DotNetObjectReference<FroalaEditor>? dotNetHelper;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new();

    private string _froalaId = "froala-editor";

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            dotNetHelper = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setDotNetHelper",  dotNetHelper);
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("createEditor", _cts.Token, $"#{_froalaId}");
        }
    }
    
    [JSInvokable]
    public void ContentChanged()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ContentChanged");
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void Click()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Click");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        dotNetHelper?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And to be complete, the razor file looks like this.

```
<div id="@_froalaId">
    @ChildContent
</div>
```

EDIT: I have build a NuGet with this solution: [github](https://github.com/Drogecode/Drogecode.Blazor.Froala)

Comment: I can tell you that I created it practically the same way as you did. To get it working without a separate JS file is impossible. This is the way to go.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid JS, but thanks for your response.